# svn and python module, subvertpy installtion failed

Tags: python, svn

```
sudo easy_install subvertpy
```

Exception: Subversion development files not found. Please set `SVN_PREFIX` or (`SVN_LIBRARY_PATH and SVN_HEADER_PATH`) environment variable

anyone who knows what happened??? SVN_PREFIX??? how to find it.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install python-subvertpy`

Comment: Are you on a Mac?  Linux?  Windows?

Answer (score 1):

if you use Mac,you can try `brew install subversion`，
then retry`sudo easy_install subvertpy`